# Add content dynamically to UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uiscrollview

So I think a UIScrollView is the best way to achieve what I want.

I will be adding 1 pixel width lines to the right side of a view every 1 second. I only want the last x number of lines shown on the screen, but then the ability to slide backwards and view previous ones.

For an example of what the view will look like:

[image: Lines]

From what I can tell I should use a UIScrollView to achieve this, but it seems that that wants you to define the width and number to render ahead of time, but I will be adding it dynamically while the user is using my app.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using a scrollView will be pretty complicated. My suggestion is you could use a `collectionView` for that and use `insertRowAtIndexPath:` to insert new rows.

You will implement the delegate method for the cell size, looking something like this :

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return CGSizeMake(1, CGRectGetHeight(collectionView.frame));
}
```

Then you just need to set different colors for the cells background.

Let me know how it went or if you have questions.

Comment: What an excellent suggestion! Thanks. I just set it up and it seems to be perfect! Never thought of trying to use that.

Comment: It's great that it worked out so fast. You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Check this Solution

`CGFloat width = self.scrollView.bounds.size.width;
CGFloat height = self.scrollView.bounds.size.height;//CGRectGetMaxY(textField.frame);
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);`